# Compiler fails to import type from global.d.ts

Tags: typescript

[Here is the full NPM package on GitHub.](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/TypeScriptGlobalTypeDeclarations)

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

global.d.ts

```
interface Foo { }
```

index.ts

```
const x: Foo = {};
```

This is what happens when we build:

```
$ \node_modules\.bin\tsc .\index.ts
index.ts(1,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Foo'.
```

This is our version:

```
$ .\node_modules\.bin\tsc --version
Version 2.3.4
```

These are the files that tsc lists:

```
$ .\node_modules\.bin\tsc --listFiles
C:/temp/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts
C:/temp/global.d.ts                         
C:/temp/index.ts
```

How can we automatically load `Foo` into the index.ts file?

### Research

[The documentation on global.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) indicates that the above should work.

Comment: This should work. Do you have a `tsconfig.json`? If so post it.

Comment: @Saravana I've posted the tsconfig file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the `global.d.ts` file as part of the `tsc`'s argument as well:

```
$ \node_modules\.bin\tsc .\index.ts .\global.d.ts
```

But note that by specifying the files you are ignoring your `tsconfig.json` file. So if you want to use your `tsconfig.json` file, just call `tsc` without any parameters and it will use the files listed when you do `tsc --listFiles`.

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json
>   files are ignored.